# Beautifulsoup scraper and if...else

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've written a scraper that parses 1 html page with changing values.

This code must find the word `Test` on the page. When it find this word ("True"), it must print `I find`, and when it's `False` - print `None`.

But when I run code it print `I find` despite the fact that it's False.
Where is the error?

```
search = soup.find('Test')
if search:
    print 'I find'
else:
    print 'None'
```

Comment: is there any tag called `Test` ?

Comment: what does `print(search)` gives you ?

Comment: I remembered that `soup.find()` will return `None` if there's nothing found so it'll never be `False`. But also, `if None:` will give `False`. And then, `soup.find()` only search HTML tag on page...

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
search = soup.find_all('Test')
if len(search)>0:
    print 'I find'
else:
    print 'None'
```

or:

```
search = soup.select('Test')
if len(search)>0:
    print 'I find'
else:
    print 'None'
```